# Why does Filehippo have updates earlier then the original site?

Tags: windows, updates

`FileHippo.com` is a software archive where you can get the newest software. It is used/linked to by many developer which implies that this site is trustworthy.

I dont get how FileHippo can have updates of software like Java faster than the original website. For instance: the Javacheck on the original site tells me that I have the newest version:

[image]

While FileHippo tells me:

[image]

This is one of many examples (Pidgin Internet Messenger offers the newest update later then filehippo too).

Maybe they have a deal with FileHippo? Maybe FileHippo scans their website for nightlybuilds/just released content in the forums?

At first I thought that filehippo could be a scam/virussite but it is promoted by many sites/developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the FileHippo.com Update Checker is actually reporting the latest version for the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) as 1.7.0.3, and the check on java.com was behind. (At the time of this writing, Java 7 (JRE 1.7.x.x) is considered pre-release software, while Java 6 (JRE 1.6.x.x) is the stable version). Why that is the case is probably just bad programming on Oracle's part.

There's also a possibility that FileHippo.com Update Checker is showing beta versions on the results page. This is the default setting. You can turn the setting off if you like.

I've used the Update Checker for a few years, and haven't run into any problems. I scan all my downloads as precaution, no matter where I get them.

Comment: so java and co are just little slow in updating their main sites while filehippo gets access and hosts them quicker on their servers? beta versions have their own area. this update was a normal one. I have used the update checker for several years now and never had "problems" either. this question just stuck in my head for several month now.

Comment: @Wandang That is probably the case. From their about page, the manually choose which software to host. You could try contacting them directly if you're still curious.